# TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len() with a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, nonetype

```
data = {}
for i, j in zip(key_names, file_names):
    data[i] = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(csv_path, j))
    if data[i].empty:
        data[i] = " "
data.keys()

from nbresult import ChallengeResult
from olist.data import Olist
data = Olist().get_data()
result = ChallengeResult('get_data', 
        keys_len=len(data), 
        keys=sorted(list(data.keys())),                 
        columns=sorted(list(data['sellers'].columns))
    )
result.write()
print(result.check())
```

I am getting the error. When running the iteration, the type of data is dict. However, when i run the 2nd paragraph, the type of data changes to NoneType. Even after adding the selection statement in, the error has continued to occur. Any help would be much appreciated.

Seems to be an issue with the line:

> `data = Olist().get_data()`

Comment: You're reassigning `data` in the second block of code, which is why it's different from in the first block. If you're expecting `Olist().get_data()` to return some value, then the problem is with that class and method. Is that a third-party library or your own code?

Comment: third-party library